# Variable has not accessed from inner class

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I have inner class which run code in UI thread and I need to pass variable to run() method.

I try to pass final res without array but I've got an error that it's necessary to use array res[0]. 
In this case I need to initialize res[] because it throws `NullPointerException`.

Are there any other way to pass variable into inner class?

```
private String sendRequest(String url, String... data) {
        final Connection.Response[] res = {};
        ...
        try {
            final Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                    .cookies(cookies)
                    .timeout(30000)
                    .ignoreContentType(true);
            if (data != null) {
                connection.data(data);
            }

            ((Activity) con).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        res[0] = connection.execute();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            result = Jsoup.parse(res[0].parse().outerHtml(), "UTF-8").text();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`res[]` is defined as an empty array (no locations), then you try to assign to something to location 0 in `res[]`, there is no location 0 because it needs to be given a size...

```
final Connection.Response[] res = new Connection.Response[requiredArraySize];
```

In your case, `requiredArraySize` is probably 1.

Comment: I understand that but how I could initialize it? I try to find alternative way.

Comment: Thanks, this is the simplest way, I don't know why I didn't try it early.